# Is there a way to reduce size of my SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to fetch all details that I need from Stores, Offers, Products and Jobs tables in 1 SQL query.

Database relations:

- Offer belongs_to Store
- Offer has_many Products
- Offer has_many Jobs

The problem is: **I want to have job counts for different jobs statuses.**

The query below **does work**, but I don't like how large it is, and has multiple duplicates of this part: `WHERE "jobs"."offer_id" = "offers"."id"`. Is there are way to make this query **optimized** and maybe smaller in size?

```
        SELECT
        "offers".*,
        "stores"."name" AS store_name,
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM "products"
          WHERE "products"."offer_id" = "offers"."id"
        ) AS products_count,
        ( 
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM "jobs"
          WHERE "jobs"."offer_id" = "offers"."id"
        ) AS jobs_count,
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM "jobs"
          WHERE "jobs"."offer_id" = "offers"."id" AND "jobs"."status" = 1
        ) AS jobs_in_progress_count,
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM "jobs"
          WHERE "jobs"."offer_id" = "offers"."id" AND "jobs"."status" = 2
        ) AS jobs_done_count,
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM "jobs"
          WHERE "jobs"."offer_id" = "offers"."id" AND "jobs"."status" = 3
        ) AS jobs_error_count
        FROM "offers"
        LEFT JOIN "stores" ON "stores"."id" = "offers"."store_id"
        GROUP BY "offers"."id", "stores"."name"
        ORDER BY "offers"."created_at" DESC
```

```
        SELECT
          "offers".*,
          "stores"."name" AS store_name,
          products.products_count,
          jobs.jobs_count,
          jobs.jobs_in_progress_count,
          jobs.jobs_done_count,
          jobs.jobs_error_count
        FROM "offers" 
        LEFT JOIN "stores" ON "stores"."id" = "offers"."store_id"
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT p.offer_id,
            COUNT(*) AS products_count
          FROM "products" p
          GROUP BY p.offer_id
        ) "products" ON "products"."offer_id" = "offers"."id"
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT j.offer_id,
            COUNT(*) AS jobs_count,
            COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE j.status = 1) AS jobs_in_progress_count,
            COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE j.status = 2) AS jobs_done_count,
            COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE j.status = 3) AS jobs_error_count
          FROM "jobs" j
          GROUP BY j.offer_id
        ) "jobs" ON "jobs"."offer_id" = "offers"."id"
        GROUP BY "offers"."id", "stores"."name", "products"."products_count", "jobs"."jobs_count", "jobs"."jobs_in_progress_count", "jobs"."jobs_done_count", "jobs"."jobs_error_count"
        ORDER BY "offers"."created_at" DESC
```

Comment: I think you can do left joins to each table (products, jobs, etc.) and do something like `SELECT COUNT(products.id) as products_count`, `SELECT COUNT(jobs.id) as jobs_count`, etc

Comment: if I left join (products, jobs) query time goes from 5ms to 50ms for some reason. I am using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to count the different jobs:

```
SELECT "offers".*,
       "stores"."name" AS store_name,
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM "products"
          WHERE "products"."offer_id" = "offers"."id"
        ) AS products_count,
        count(jobs.offer_id) as jobs_count,
        count(jobs.offer_id) filter (where jobs.status = 1) as jobs_in_progress_count,
        count(jobs.offer_id) filter (where jobs.status = 2) as jobs_done_count,
        count(jobs.offer_id) filter (where jobs.status = 3) as jobs_error_count
FROM "offers"
  LEFT JOIN "stores" ON "stores"."id" = "offers"."store_id"
  LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobs.offer_id = offers.id 
GROUP BY "offers"."id", "stores"."name"
ORDER BY "offers"."created_at" DESC;
```

Aggregating first, then joining to the result of that might be faster:

```sql
SELECT "offers".*,
       "stores"."name" AS store_name,
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM "products"
          WHERE "products"."offer_id" = "offers"."id"
        ) AS products_count,
        jobs.jobs_count,
        jobs.jobs_in_progress_count,
        jobs.jobs_done_count,
        jobs.jobs_error_count
FROM "offers"
  LEFT JOIN "stores" ON "stores"."id" = "offers"."store_id"
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT j.offer_id,
          count(*) as jobs_count,
          count(*) filter (where j.status = 1) as jobs_in_progress_count,
          count(*) filter (where j.status = 2) as jobs_done_count,
          count(*) filter (where j.status = 3) as jobs_error_count
    FROM jobs j
    group by j.offer_id
  ) jobs ON jobs.offer_id = offers.id 
ORDER BY "offers"."created_at" DESC;
```

This could also be done for counting the products:

```sql
SELECT "offers".*,
       "stores"."name" AS store_name,
        prod.products_count,
        jobs.jobs_count,
        jobs.jobs_in_progress_count,
        jobs.jobs_done_count,
        jobs.jobs_error_count
FROM "offers"
  LEFT JOIN "stores" ON "stores"."id" = "offers"."store_id"
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT j.offer_id,
          count(*) as jobs_count,
          count(*) filter (where j.status = 1) as jobs_in_progress_count,
          count(*) filter (where j.status = 2) as jobs_done_count,
          count(*) filter (where j.status = 3) as jobs_error_count
    FROM jobs j
    group by j.offer_id
  ) jobs ON jobs.offer_id = offers.id 
  LEFT JOIN (
     select p.offer_id, count(*)
     from products p
     group by p.offer_id
  ) prod on prod.offer_id = offers.id
ORDER BY "offers"."created_at" DESC;
```

Comment: For some reason if I remove grouping `GROUP BY "offers"."id", "stores"."name", "products"."products_count", "jobs"."jobs_count", "jobs"."jobs_in_progress_count", "jobs"."jobs_done_count", "jobs"."jobs_error_count"` before `ORDER BY`, then it does not work. I am using PostgreSQL, why do I need to group on everything I select?

Comment: @totheflo: you need it for the first query, but not the other two.

Comment: I am using 3rd query you provided, but if I remove anything from `GROUP BY` statement PostgreSQL complains (I am using Rails)

Comment: @totheflo: no idea. I am certain that the third query as written does not require a GROUP BY in the main query. Did you change or add anything to it?

Comment: No, I just changed `prod` to `products` and added some quotes. (I have edited first post, to show full query I am using)